# Auth0 Login&Logout profile not working. React typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, auth0

I have an issue with Auth0. Login. And Logout. with react typescript.

Here is in Index.tsx.

```
root.render(
  <Auth0Provider
        domain="somecode.us.auth0.com"
        clientId="somecode" 
        authorizationParams={{
          redirect_uri: window.location.origin
        }}
      >
      <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <App />
        </Provider>
      </React.StrictMode>
  </Auth0Provider>
);
```

Some code was given in auth config.

Now I have an login or logout button.

```
const AuthButton = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect, logout } = useAuth0();

  const handleLogin = () => {
    loginWithRedirect();
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {
    logout({ logoutParams: { returnTo: window.location.origin } });
  };

  return (
    <button
      style={{
        color: 'white',
        backgroundColor: '#142952',
        marginRight: '4rem',
        fontFamily: 'Consolas',
        border: 'none',
        borderRadius: '3px',
        width: '110px',
        height: '40px'
      }}
      onClick={isAuthenticated ? handleLogout : handleLogin}
    >
      {isAuthenticated ? 'Logout' : 'Login'}
    </button>
  );
};

export default AuthButton;
```

As well. I retrieve user information to show.

```
const Profile = () => {
  const { user, isAuthenticated, getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAccessToken = async () => {
      try {
        const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
        setAccessToken(token);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    if (isAuthenticated) {
      getAccessToken();
      console.log("authenticated")
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated, getAccessTokenSilently]);

  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return <div>Please login to view your profile.</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {user?.picture && (
        <img src={user.picture} alt="Profile Picture" />
      )}
      <h2>Hello {user?.name}</h2>
      <p>Email: {user?.email}</p>
      <p>Login Method: {user?.sub?.split('|')[0]}</p>
      <p>Access Token: {accessToken}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

## **Here is my problem**: **the login logout button does not change** after I login into the Auth0 protocol. First. It opens and go to the auth0 dialog. However. After login in with my google account. Then the button still says "Login". **Which means that it never login**. I dont really know what to do. Here is the auth0 config settings I do have.

[image]

explained already in above

Comment: Here are some hints on how to get more knowledge: 1) Check auth0 logs at the Dashboard under "Monitoring -> Logs". 2) Check network traffic and see if your login succeeds or fails. If it succeeds, check if you see a successful call to https://[YOUR DOMAIN]/authorize followed by a request to https://[YOUR DOMAIN]/token. The access_token that you get back from the latter request should validate if you copy it to https://jwt.io Update your question and let us know what you see. :)

Comment: Hello Andreas. It works with the local  http://localhost:3000/home. But as long as I want to use the domain tourismcycling.com . Then it crashes. It logs in but it does not redictect to tourismcycling.com/home

Comment: Ok. I finally find the solution of the problem. To make the website work. I used loginWithPopup() which make everything works. It works for both localhost and also the specific domain.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by using loginWithPopup instead of loginredirect. I also used the link.

```
authorizationParams={{
redirect_uri: 'mysiteadress.com/home'
}}
```

I did not use window.location.origin. But instead I used the adress in that part of the code.